# Intermittent fasting

Tags: diet

In intermittent fasting does the fasting period start immediately after your last meal Or only after your body digested the food? I can never figure this out.

Comment: Nutrition questions are off topic.

Comment: How would you know when your body digested the food? My understanding is that the fasting clock starts every time you stop putting food in your mouth.

Comment: Hi @Ross, questions about nutrition only are off-topic, they need to be somehow related to your exercise regime. If you can add any relevant context, I'm happy to reopen the question for you

Answer (score 2):

It occurs RIGHT after you finish eating.